# Querying results of an aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to, in a single Elasticsearch query expression, perform both an aggregation and then execute a bool query over the resultset produced by that aggregation?

For instance, consider the following dataset and data transformations. I want elastic to execute:

**1) Initial Dataset (content within the Elasticsearch index):**

```
{ "pivot_id":  "A", "version": 1, "value": "x" }
{ "pivot_id":  "A", "version": 2, "value": "y" }
{ "pivot_id":  "A", "version": 3, "value": "z" }
{ "pivot_id":  "B", "version": 1, "value": "w" }
{ "pivot_id":  "B", "version": 2, "value": "k" }
```

**2) Aggregate by pivot_id:**

```
{ "pivot_id":  "A", "version": 1, "value": "x" ] // bucket: A
{ "pivot_id":  "A", "version": 2, "value": "y" }
{ "pivot_id":  "A", "version": 3, "value": "z" }

{ "pivot_id":  "B", "version": 1, "value": "w" } // bucket: B
{ "pivot_id":  "B", "version": 2, "value": "k" }
```

**3) Pick the most recent version of each pivot_id/bucket:**

```
{ "pivot_id":  "A", "version": 1, "value": "x" }
{ "pivot_id":  "B", "version": 1, "value": "w" }
```

**4) And then execute a simple bool query with pagination and sorting over the dataset in 3)**

That is, how can I in a single Elasticsearch query expression perform the above sequence/pipeline of data transformations `1->2->3->4`?

I've tried the below approach but I had no success because the `query bool` is being executed to feed the `aggs` caluse, and not to be used over the resultset produced by the `trx_id_group aggs`.
That is, elastic is executing: `4->1->2->3`, and not `1->2->3->4` as I wish.

Is there a way to enforce bool queries to be applied on top of aggregated results (aggs->query), and not (query->aggs)?

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.2.4.

My unsuccessful attempt:

```
GET /index/_search
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,

    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "terms": {
                    "value.keyword": ["y", "w"]
                }
            }]
        }
    },

    "aggs": {
        "trx_id_group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "trx_id.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "most_recent_per_group": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [{
                            "version": {
                                "order": "desc"
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "version": "asc"
    }]
}
```

For this query I was expecting no results, since the most recent versions of documents `A` and `B` doesn't have the `y` and `w` values. Yet the query is fetching and grouping events `A.v2` and `B.v1`.

**Last note:** In `SQL` the above query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT a.PIVOT_ID, a.VERSION, a.VALUE
      FROM ES_INDEX AS a
      INNER JOIN (SELECT PIVOT_ID, MAX(VERSION) AS VERSION
                  FROM ES_INDEX
                  GROUP BY PIVOT_ID) AS b
      ON a.PIVOT_ID = b.PIVOT_ID AND a.VERSION = b.VERSION) AS TRX_ID_MOST_RECENT_VERSION
 WHERE // ... your custom SEARCH clauses here ...
```

I've tried to use Elasticsearch's [SQL Translate API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/sql-translate.html) but unfortunately translation of `INNER JOIN` operations are not yet supported.

Thank you all! :)

Comment: I don't think this is possible. There are ways to do stuff with the results of aggregations (pipeline aggregations), but not the way you want it. I know that everyone wishes to use a single query that can do magic, but with ES is not always possible or practical. Have you considered populating a second index with the results of your steps 1->2->3 and then run the queries you want on this index with the "aggregated" data?

Comment: @AndreiStefan, yup! most likely I will end up by creating/maintaining a second index holding just the most recent version for each document. I was trying to avoid this approach since it entails some data duplication -- and thus, a more expensive data storage solution.

Comment: You could minimize the amount of data stored in the second index by just indexing the fields you need in your searches, and not also storing them. After you run the query you could retrieve back the actual documents from the "main" index.